# Change size of label/legend in alluvial plot (ggalluvial) and split a categorical variable with many categories in half

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalluvial

I´m trying to alter a basic alluvial plot in order to fit my data and I have two separate issues:

- two of the categories (A1 & A2) within my main variable (index) are much much larger in relation to the others which makes the rest of the outcomes to look squeezed in.
- the second variable I´m using has also many categories in it which makes the legend too big to fit withing the margin of the graph

I use the following code_

```
ggplot(data = sni_long, 
       aes(axis1 = index, axis2 = Avdelning, y = freq)) + 
 geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Avdelning)) + 
 geom_stratum() + 
 geom_text(stat = "stratum", 
           aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) + 
 scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Index", "Avdelning"), 
                  expand = c(0.15, 0.05)) +  
 theme_void()
```

and get the following graph:[image]

when I tried the following code hoping to split my axis1 variable (index) in half:

```
ggplot(data = sni_long,
       aes(axis1 = index,   
           axis2 = Avdelning, 
           axis3 = index,   
           y = freq)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Avdelning)) +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum",
            aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Index", "Avdelning"),
                   expand = c(0.15, 0.05)) +
  theme_void()
```

I only managed to mirror the graph:
[image]

and as you see in both cases, the legend falls outside the scope of the graph :S

Edit: dataset here:

```
sni_long<- structure(list(Avdelning = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
                                                      "H", "I", "J", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "A", "B", "C", 
                                                      "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", 
                                                      "S", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "L", "M", 
                                                      "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
                                                      "I", "J", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "A", "B", "C", "D", 
                                                      "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", 
                                                      "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "L", "M", "N", 
                                                      "P", "Q", "R", "S", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", 
                                                      "J", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
                                                      "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "A", 
                                                      "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "L", "M", "N", "P", 
                                                      "Q", "R", "S", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", 
                                                      "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S"), index = c("A1", "A1", "A1", 
                                                                                                    "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
                                                                                                    "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
                                                                                                    "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", 
                                                                                                    "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", 
                                                                                                    "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
                                                                                                    "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B2", 
                                                                                                    "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", 
                                                                                                    "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", 
                                                                                                    "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", 
                                                                                                    "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", 
                                                                                                    "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", 
                                                                                                    "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", 
                                                                                                    "C2", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
                                                                                                    "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
                                                                                                    "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
                                                                                                    "D2", "D2"), freq = c(91, 15, 958, 82, 74, 1338, 1296, 591, 295, 
                                                                                                                          905, 286, 1074, 751, 237, 602, 104, 101, 3896, 96, 6585, 274, 
                                                                                                                          328, 12885, 14708, 4308, 4647, 5685, 3808, 13722, 4656, 2066, 
                                                                                                                          3466, 1592, 2425, 16, 7, 430, 44, 28, 305, 386, 154, 8, 268, 
                                                                                                                          79, 295, 129, 71, 160, 12, 16, 29, 5, 264, 22, 20, 410, 405, 
                                                                                                                          192, 108, 348, 78, 400, 324, 67, 258, 33, 32, 10, 4, 172, 14, 
                                                                                                                          13, 214, 270, 112, 45, 191, 38, 236, 187, 52, 167, 11, 24, 18, 
                                                                                                                          7, 229, 20, 14, 161, 215, 79, 6, 176, 45, 174, 89, 38, 93, 6, 
                                                                                                                          9, 72, 3, 138, 8, 9, 464, 310, 178, 190, 235, 81, 385, 252, 61, 
                                                                                                                          147, 40, 47, 39, 2, 44, 2, 2, 145, 104, 37, 23, 54, 41, 101, 
                                                                                                                          36, 11, 25, 8, 13, 18, 1, 137, 12, 16, 268, 212, 123, 39, 218, 
                                                                                                                          39, 219, 178, 48, 133, 22, 13, 13, 0, 67, 7, 12, 206, 159, 96, 
                                                                                                                          38, 160, 26, 160, 160, 36, 120, 22, 9)), row.names = c(NA, -170L
                                                                                                                          ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?